# For a matrix with complex & real numbers, how to find conditions when eigenvalues are real & eigenvectors orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is related to linear algebra and is from one my assignments. I don't know the textbook where it came from. I'm mostly looking for good hints on how to solve part b) and c).
Given a matrix B
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & 0 \\
x_2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $x_1$ and $x_2$ being complex numbers.

a) find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors
b) find the conditions for the eigenvalues to be real
c) find the conditions for the eigenvectors to be orthogonal.

for part a) I found the characteristic equation to be:
$$(1-\lambda)[(1-\lambda)^2 -x_1*x_2] = 0$$
the eigenvalues:
$$1, 
1 + \sqrt{x_1*x_2}, 
1 - \sqrt{x_1*x_2}$$
and the corresponding eigenvectors:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1/\sqrt{x_1*x_2} \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-x_1/\sqrt{x_1*x_2} \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to answer b) or part c)

for b) is the answer that the only way for the eigenvalues to be real is if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are complex conjugates of each other, because their multiplication would yield a real number in the second and third eigenvalue?
c) do i just need to take the dot product of the vectors with each other other set them to zero, and solve for $x_1$ in terms of $x_2?$

thanks in advance for the answers.

(This is my first post here. I followed the MathJax instructions. If the matrices don't end-up showing up properly I'll try to write them in a different way)

Comment: $x_1x_2 >0$ does not imply $x_1, x_2$ are complex conjugate. Otherwise, seems OK.

Comment: @Elb What exactly do you mean by a "dot-product" for vectors that contain complex entries?

Comment: @dsh that's a good point. I guess for part b) then the conditions for the matrix to be real would be that x_1 and x_2 to be complex conjugates of each other and x_1*x_2>0.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Part c) of the question asks to find the conditions for when the eigenvectors are orthogonal. One simple way to find-out if two vectors are orthogonal is to take their vector dot-product and if the result is 0 (zero), then they are orthogonal. So, I was thinking of using this method for part c) by taking the vector dot-product of  two of the eigenvectors at a time and set it to zero, then solve for x_1 in terms of x_2. I would then repeat this two more time to account for the two other possible eigenvector dot-products.

Comment: @ElbCox3 Again, what do you mean by the "vector dot-product" when you have vectors with complex entries? My question is really whether your dot-product (and associated notion of orthogonality) involves a complex conjugate in the formula.

Comment: @ Ben Grossman, i didn't realize you were asking a rhetorical question. But you're right that I need to read up more on orthogonality and complex numbers. thanks.